# NSPredicate is not working on some object

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nspredicate

I am having array contains model, in that model i am haveing 3 objects as String say, `firstName`, `lastName` and `action`,

i am using the following predicate

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName CONTAINS [c] %@ OR firstName CONTAINS [c] %@ OR action CONTAINS [c] %@", searchText, searchText, searchText)            
tableDataArray = dataSourceArray.filter { resultPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }
```

if i search the string based on `firstName` or `lastName` its working fine. But if i search the string which is present in the `action` its not filtering. 
Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: show examples of what works and what doesn't, include the array contents you're searching and the definition of the model class

Comment: Is there a reason for searchText being cast to NSString?

Comment: @Naoto nope... i just tried with that option also thats all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really its strange... i unable to find the solution for this. But i found the alternate way to filter the array without using predicate.

```
tableDataArray = dataSourceArray.filter {$0.firstName.containsString(searchText) || $0.lastName.containsString(searchText) || $0.action.containsString(searchText) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Me to faced some issue, after many article i referred, found the solution

extension yourModelclassName {

    @objc override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        switch key {
        case "firstName":
            return firstName
        case "lastName":
            return lastName
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

//Please put the given code in your model class like i gave above, it will work fine.
```